# Coletor de Dados MX7

Tags: lazarus

Alguém sabe como eu coloco um ENTER automático após a leitura do código de barras no coletor Modelo MX7 da Honeywell, procurei no manual mas não encontrei nada que poderia me ajudar.

Comment: Como assim um "enter"? Você quer ler o código de barras "12345" e quer que apareça "12345\n"?

Comment: OLá, acho que esta resposta você pode encontrar neste link: https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-configure-an-automatic-ENTER-CR-or-TAB-on-Intermec-Computers